# How can I solve this error in Python concerning minizinc package?

Tags: python, minizinc

I have the following code:

```
from minizinc import Instance, Model, Solver

MODEL = "model1.mzn"
DATA = "ins-1.dzn"

# Loading the model
model = Model(MODEL)
model.add_file(DATA)

# Find the MiniZinc solver configuration for Gecode
gecode = Solver.lookup("gecode")

# Create an Instance of the model for Gecode
instance = Instance(gecode,model)

# solution and creation of an output file
result = instance.solve()

# loading solution in an ouptput file
with open(DATA[:-4] + "_output.txt","w") as file:
    file.write(instance["w"] + " " + result["l"] + "\n")
    num_circuits = instance["n"]
    file.write(num_circuits + "\n")
    for i in num_circuits:
        file.write(instance["x"][i] + " " + instance["y"][i] + " ")
        file.write(result["p"][i][0] + " " + result["p"][i][1] + "\n")
```

After the execution I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/boezi/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/output_solution.py", line 23, in <module>
    file.write(instance["w"] + " " + result["l"] + "\n")
  File "C:\Users\boezi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\minizinc\model.py", line 145, in __getitem__
    return self._data.__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'w'
```

It seems as the keyword "w" does not exist but I have defined it in my mzn file:

```
% width of the plate
int: w;
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with this library, but a guess to help you out?

https://minizinc-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

It looks like you need to assign "w" a value?

ex.

`instance["w"] = 4`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did not want to add directly a value but I wanted to load values from a dzn file that I have added with `model.add_file(DATA)` statement, maybe there is something wrong in loading dzn in this way

Comment: You would have to use the `dzn` extra (`pip install minizinc[dzn]`) and enable the `parse` flag in the `add_file` method. Otherwise you do not have direct access to the information in the data files, only the assignment to the variables in the solution

Comment: Thank you so much, I installed minizinc[dzn] but the flag was not enabled